# MOSS 2007 Excel Services Webpart Formatting

Tags: 2007, excel-services

Is there an easy way (i.e without programming & deploying a custom webpart) to remove the column/row headers in an Excel webpart view on a MOSS 2007 site?  Customer sees:

```
     A      B      C      D
1   xxxx    xxx   xx     xxx
2    ---      -    -      --
```

Just wants the data, not the a,b,c,d,1,2,... default column/row headers.  Can't find the option/group of options to do this in the Modify Shared Web Part display options.

Answer (score 2):

Simply go into the spreadsheet, select the area to be displayed, right click, and give the range a name.  Then go into the web part, and type in the named range.  Poof, no more column and row headers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a kludge, but you could hide them with jQuery on the client side if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by hiding the rows and column indicators in the original (source) spreadsheet in Excel.